# WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio 3.3.1 and This occurs after importing old project and a popup said to update your gradle version and when I click update after 3,4 seconds this error occurs.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Just replace compile by api or implementation depending if you want to expose your dependencies or not.

Comment: from where i can replace these things? i am beginner.

Comment: Based on the error message there should be in the app directory a build.gradle file. There is a section dependencies there you should find compile and testCompile replace them by api and testApi

Comment: Replace `compile` with `implementation`

Answer (score 3):

At the left menu, you can see `Gradle Scripts`, click it and expand it, then look for the `build.gradle(Module: app)` then in dependencies part if you see any 'compile' change it to `implementation`. look at the image for better understanding:

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Remove the word `compile` and used `implementation` instead.

`compile` is now changed with `imolementation`.

Also with the image you provide, I see that you have to change `testCompile` with `testImplementation`.